# How to get the specific highlighted region in pdf which uses pdfjs

Tags: angularjs, canvas, pdf.js

I have a pdf which is having some highlighted region inside it. When user click on any part of PDF, I want to know whether he/she clicked on the highlighted region or not. I have done some research on that and found that the highlighting is actually happening in the canvas not in the textLayer. So now I'm not sure how do we actually detect that the click action happened on highlighted region or not. I have the coordinates available related to the highlighted area of the pdf, I can write a function to find whether click coordinates are inside the boundary of the highlighted area coordinates, but the problem is that I also need to make sure that when user hover on the highlighted area, I need to show pointer cursor so that user knows it is clickable. To achieve this pointer cursor on hover I have to do the calculation on every mouse move which will slow down performance. I'm looking for solution for this on how to solve.

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AI5pV1Mq-xXCwjE&cid=8966C5137849E869&id=8966C5137849E869%2120538&parId=root&o=OneUp) is the sample pdf, region in the green color is what I'm talking about.

I have tried searching it online to find whether there is anyone who posted question similar to this but I could not find anything relative.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by manually creating a rectangle div inside the textLayer div. Since I have access to the rectangle coordinates for the pdf, I have used coordinates values and creating a rectangle there which will have a class and id and when user hover or click on that particular div then I'm checking whether target div is having the id that we provided and taking action based on that.